# Connecting a Powervault 220 to R805

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, raid-controller, dell-powervault

I'm trying to connect a dell powervault 220 to a dell poweredge R805  I bought a PCI express SCSI Card for the 805 (Adaptec 29320LPE) and plugged the vault into it.  The server sees the card because I get the option to go in and configure the card itself, but when I go into the raid controller, I can't see the power vault, I only see the 2 internal drives.  Is there a different spot I need to go, or do I have an issue with the scsi card?  I have the same problem with my 2850 with a different card.  I can't see the powervault in the Raid controller window on the server.

here's the documentation: [Adaptec.com](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/scsi/u320/asc-29320lpe/)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Sounds l like you are going into the internal PERC controller and not the Adaptec RAID card. Do you see two cards POST at startup or just one?

Comment: I thought the powervault was supposed to show up as a second channel on the internal raid controller menu.  There is a boot option to go into the adaptec card, but all it lets me do is change the SCSI ID from the default 7 to another option.

Comment: If you are using Dell branded PERC controllers that are supported on the system and the PV then yes that is how it would work. But, if you are using your own controller that does not have the dell firmware on it then it doesn't know how to communicate with the existing controller.

Comment: Also, this is a 10th Gen servers, i know that is true of 12 and 13 Gen servers, 11Gen you had to go into each controller individually

Comment: Okay.  I'll see if there are some options I'm missing in the adaptec controller.

Comment: You were correct in part of the way.  The settings were indeed in that menu.  The second issue was that the port the scsi cable was plugged into on the powervault seems not to work.  Using the other port resulted in the harddrives appearing.  If you move your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Dell branded PERC controllers that are supported on the system and the PV then yes that is how it would work. But, if you are using your own controller that does not have the dell firmware on it then it doesn't know how to communicate with the existing controller.